# Calling argument in parametrized constructor in method - C++

Tags: c++, class

I'm new at programming. I wondered if you were to call a specific argument in the parameter for your constructor, which you had to use in your method, then how would you do it with pointers? I solved it by the use of 'this' because the local variable name is the same as the member variable's name, but I just wanted to see how it is possible by the use of normal pointers and not the this pointer.

Here is the code I worked on.

BMR.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class BMR
{
public:
    BMR();
    BMR(char, int, int, int);
    int calculateBMR();

private:
    int weight;
    int height;
    int age;
    char gender;
};
```

BMR.cpp

```
#include "BMR.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
BMR::BMR()
{

}

BMR::BMR(char k, int h, int w, int a)
{
   gender = k;
   height = h;
   weight = w;
   age = a;  
}

int BMR::calculateBMR()
{
    int BMR;
    if(this->gender == 'M')
    {
        BMR = 10 * weight + (6.25 * height - (5*age)) + 5;
        cout << "Man: " << BMR << endl;
    }

    if(this->gender == 'W')
    {
        BMR = 10 * weight + (6.25 * height - (5*age)) - 161;
        cout << "Woman: " << BMR << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. Are you trying to pass a function as an argument to another function and call it? What do you want to do with pointers?

Comment: I want to call my gender member variable in the constructor of BMR in my method calculatBMR()

Comment: What constructor? No constructor is called in `calculateBMR()`. You first create an object of type BMR somewhere (e.g. in `main()`), the constructor initializes member variables and after this is done, you can call `calculateBMR()` on the object. Also, you can only "call" a function, not a member variable.

Comment: In my constructor BMR, I have my member variable gender as one of the parameters, that specifies if the subject is a man or a woman. If I have to calculate the BMR in the method calculateBMR() I have to know the gender of the subject, that is where I used my 'this' pointer. I asked if it was possible to make a pointer that could then point to the gender of my subject in the constructor.

Comment: You don't need to use `this` pointer explicitly. If you remove it, it will work just as `height` and `weight` work. You only need `this` if you have local variable with the same name (and you don't have that here).